# one generation away

Tags: comprehension

Example with [a context](http://news.yahoo.com/signs-alien-life-found-2025-nasas-chief-scientist-212655192.html):

> Former astronaut John Grunsfeld, associate administrator for NASA's Science Mission Directorate, shared Stofan's optimism, predicting that signs of life will be found relatively soon both in our own solar system and beyond.
>   "I think we're **one generation away** in our solar system, whether it's on an icy moon or on Mars, and **one generation [away]** on a planet around a nearby star," Grunsfeld said during Tuesday's event.

I'm not sure what he really means by *one generation away* and how we should understand it.

Comment: I guess it's either a generation of spacecrafts or a generation of us, the people of Earth. I think it's the latter. [generation](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/generation): "1a. the number of years that usually pass between the birth of a person and the birth of that person’s children".

Comment: Grunsfield means he doesn't think *he* will be among those who discover evidence of life on another planet/moon, but his *children* (or others of the same age) will. And I'm sure he means it'll be ***another*** generation (i.e. - his children's children) who will discover life somewhere beyond the solar system. The important bit being that he takes it for granted extraterrestrial life *does exist*, so finding it is just a matter of (relatively short) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're one generation away means we are at the distance (in time) of one generation.

Comment: welcome back! :)